# Cytoscape cy png creating empty image

Tags: cytoscape.js

I'm trying to export our graph in full size but it returns an empty image.

```
cy.png({"full": true})
```

returns

```
"data:,"
```

However, if I do this:

```
tmpImg.attr('src', cy.png({ "full": true, "output": "base64url", "maxWidth": 20000, "maxHeight": 20000, "bg": "#fff" }));
```

I get a nice image exported.

The problem is the maxwidth I'm specifying is too small. If I increase it, I get an empty image again.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the [related issue](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/1943). It is because of limit on the size of file a browser can export.

What about changing the scale to something less than 1? This will reduce the quality, but might solve your problem.

Also there is an [extension](https://github.com/kinimesi/cytoscape-svg) that exports the view as SVG. Alternatively you can try it (SVG will probably have smaller size). Looks like it is under development, and I do not know how well it works.

Comment: I had thought about the size limitation but the approach when I specify the max height and width ends up with a file size of ~1.5 megs. I can't seem to increase it much without it returning an empty image.

Comment: Can you try it in Firefox? I looks like Firefox [does not have that size limit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs#Common_problems).

Comment: same issue as with Chrome